# IOS conditional view controllers under tabbars

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I am making an App with a Login system.

The tab has 4 tabs and a the home tab I want to have a conditional sub view controller where if the user is not logged in, it will be a login page, where the user is logged in, the user will be redirected to a different view controller.

I have using navigation controller in between my tabviewcontroller and tabviewcontrollers.

Dennis

Comment: Not that this is impossible, but I think there's an easier way. Check if your user is logged in before any other view comes up, then navigate to your tabbarcontroller. This is what most applications do. For example, SnapChat.

Comment: Thanks for the quick comment. I am fairly new to IOS development. I have some experience with Android and it is done in android with fragments.

Comment: Have all users go to the tab controller, and present the setup screen modally for new ones from the tab view controller.

Comment: But what is the strategy and approach I should take in IOS as you suggested

Comment: @doctordoder I was told that tabbarController should never be embedded in NavigationController, always the other way round. I'm not very sure though?

Comment: Is there a youtube video or a step by step tutorial I can follow. I'm a bit new :p

Comment: I have tabbarcontroller - navigationcontroller - tableviewcontroller structure with nagivation controller in the middle

Answer (score 1):

Just to elaborate on what @duci9y said. You could have something like this:

In the implementation of your first tab:

```
    if (!user.loggedIn)
    {
        LoginViewController *loginController = [LoginViewController new];
        [self presentViewController:loginController
                           animated:YES
                         completion:nil];
    }
```

In your login view controller

```
    // once the user has logged in
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
                             completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem. My solution is this:

1. draw a login view controller as the tab of which you want to do login.
2. draw another view controller(in my case, I use the identifier 'train')
3. implement viewDidAppear of the login tab:

Push the view controller created in step2 if the user has logged in.
Of course, you need to hide the back button in navigation bar.

```
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        if Local.HASLOGIN {
          let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
          let cont =  sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("train") as! TrainViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(cont, animated: false)
    }}
```